Dynamic variable group selection based on triggering repository
I'm trying to dynamically provide the name of a variable group in yml azure pipeline by using the predefined variable Build.Repository.Name.
I've added few repositories to the pipeline as additional resources and they trigger the pipeline based on a commit on a certain branch.
Here's current pipeline:
parameters:
 - name: repos
   type: object
   default: [repo1, repo2]
resources:
 repositories:
 - repository: repo1
   type: git
   name: project1/repo1

 - repository: repo2
   type: git
   name: project1/repo2 

jobs:
 - ${{each repo in parameters.repos}}:
  - job:
    displayName: Repo ${{ repo }}
    variables:
    - group: ${{ repo }}
    steps:
    - script: |
       if [ "$(Build.Repository.Name)" != ${{ repo }} ]; then
        echo "Skipping to the next repo"
        return 0
       fi
      displayName: Finding the trigger repository

    - template: template/do-work.yml

The above pipeline is working as it is, but it's going through all of the repositories soon I would need to add 10+ repositories and that would slow down the pipeline.
It would be perfect if the following was accepted, but in that case the value of the variable is repository where the pipeline is located, not the triggering repository:
variables:
 - group: ${{ variables['Build.Repository.Name']


Based on your requirement, you need to set the variable group name based on the triggering repository name.
I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly meet your requirement.
The variable group field will set the variable at compile time. The value pointed to by the variable: Build.Repository.Name  during compile time is the repo where the Pipeline is located.
At runtime, the value of the variable will be changed to the name of the resource repo that triggered the Pipeline.
So when we use the compile time format: - group: ${{ variables['Build.Repository.Name']}} , it will only set the repo where the Pipeline is located instead of triggering repo.
Currently, we don't have a predefined variable that can correctly read the repo name that triggers the pipeline at compile time.
For a workaround, you can split the Pipeline into two pipelines. The first Pipeline will use PowerShell/Bash script to pass the runtime variable:$(Build.Repository.Name) value to the parameter value in the Second Pipeline.
For example:
Pipeline One:
resources:
 repositories:
 - repository: repo1
   type: git
   name: project1/repo1
   
 - repository: repo2
   type: git
   name: project1/repo2 

jobs:
- job: Passvariable
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $token = "$(pat)"      
          $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Orgname}/{Projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineRunID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
          
          $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
          
          $JSON = "
          {
            
          
          
            `"resources`": {
              `"repositories`": {
                `"self`": {
                  `"ref`": `"refs/heads/main`"
                }
              }
            },
            `"templateParameters`": {
              `"Reponame`":`"$(Build.Repository.Name)`"
            },
          
          
          
          }"
          
          
          $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

Pipeline Two:
parameters:
 - name: repos
   type: object
   default: [repo1, repo2]
 - name: reponame
   type: string

resources:
 repositories:
 - repository: repo1
   type: git
   name: project1/repo1
   
 - repository: repo2
   type: git
   name: project1/repo2 

jobs:
 - ${{each repo in parameters.repos}}:
  - job:
    displayName: Repo ${{ repo }}
    variables:
    - group: ${{ paramters.reponame }}
    steps:
    - script: |
       if [ "$(Build.Repository.Name)" != ${{ repo }} ]; then
        echo "Skipping to the next repo"
        return 0
       fi
      displayName: Finding the trigger repository

    - template: template/do-work.yml


In this scenario are the resource repository triggers added on the first pipeline only?

@livanov if you don’t need to use the repo files in the  second pipeline. You can remove the resource repo in second pipeline. Or you can disable the resource repo trigger in second pipeline and only checkout the repo resources
